# Appropriate tag for cooking for one?

Tags: discussion, tags

[A recent question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/26066/how-can-i-efficiently-make-single-serve-porridge) suggested the tag 'alone-cooking', which I've personally never seen used for the concept.

I have quite a few cookbooks on that general subject, and the terms I generally see are 'solo cooking' or 'cooking for one', but I don't know that either one's obvious enough that people are going to find it right off without a few synonyms.  In the case of baking or preserving, I've seen the term 'small batch' used, but I don't know that it necessarily fits for all types of cooking.

(and before we trigger a discussion on how appropriate it is to tag by quantity, I'll point out that cooking for one or two has considerations because of the lack of economy of scale; on the opposite side of the scale, we *do* have a [bulk-cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulk-cooking) tag.)

Answer (score 5):

I've been cooking for one (or two) for basically my entire life and I still cannot conceive of this as being an area of specialization. The vast *majority* of recipes online and in cookbooks make 2-4 servings (maybe 6 if you eat like a bird) and what you don't eat, well, throw it in the fridge or freezer to use as leftovers.

I could, potentially, see a use for a tag relating to *fast* cooking, as many people (*including* professional chefs) often have very little time to cook.

As luck would have it, we already have such a tag: [shortcuts](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcuts)

Don't think I really see the value in a "cooking for solo/small groups" tag though. Sounds vaguely analogous to "white history month", i.e. redundant.